# How to get certain data from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, pandas, xlrd, xlwt

My excel sheet has many nulls and extraneous information. I am trying to build a code that will go through the second column on the excel sheet, and in that second column, if a row contains the word "precinct", "split', or a numerical value, I want to gather that data.

My pseudo code:

if column B contains precinct:
    get data from row

elif Column B contains split:
    get data from row

elif Column B contains a number:
    get data from row

else:
    do not get data

How do I go about this? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason to do the filtering as you read the excel sheet rather than processing the data after pandas reads the excel sheet in? It would be a lot easier if you read the whole sheet in and filter the dataframe based on the content in the second column.